# moved function from main to prototype now its not working

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, function-prototypes

```
struct studentType {
    string firstName;
    string lastName; 
    int testScore; 
    char Grade; 
};

studentType students[20];

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("testScores.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        inputFile >> students[i].testScore;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        cout << " " << students[i].testScore;

    return 0;
}

void firstName() {
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("firstName.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        inputFile >> students[i].testScore;
}
```

This is the original code to read a .txt file into a member of a structured array. When I write it in main it reads in the values and everything is fine. Now when I try to move it out of main into a void and use a function prototype, all numbers read 0.

When I move it I use the same code, but the function is outside of main like

```
void testScore(){
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("testScores.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        inputFile >> students[i].testScore;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        cout << " " << students[i].testScore;
}
```

with a function prototype above main. It returns all zeroes though. Clearly I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually calling your function? If you move that code to a separate function, it won't get run unless you call that function. Ex:

```
int main(void){
    testScore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I called it and then I tried to get it to display the numbers it had stored in the array elements and they are all 0.